# Jquery meta tags

Tags: jquery, meta-tags

Is there a way in Jquery to read meta tag expires and redirect. So if the page has expired than redirect it to other url otherwise be in the same page. Thanks

Comment: The browsers should be able to parse the meta tag and redirect without Javascript.

Comment: @PeterOlson has a point. Leaving that aside, `$('meta')` seems to work for me.

Comment: Redirect worked for me but expire meta tag didnt work for me so i  was wondering if there is a way by jquery to do that